# How to fix three.js loading more than 2 minutes and it's crashing

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, webgl

I'm creating a 3D game, and I just began. However, I quickly ran into a problem with the localhost GET taking more than 2 minutes, and after like 15-45 seconds of life, then the canvas turns white and in console, I get a warn showing that the WebGL context has been lost. Also, in Task Manager, the game takes up 30% of the CPU and 100% of the GPU.

It is for a new online 3d multiplayer game. I've tried to dispose the memory after a new frame, but that didn't work. I've tried also to pre-load all the textures to use less CPU, but the 30% CPU remains the same. This is my code: (client-side)

```
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000)

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    scene.autoUpdate = false;
    var preLoad = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var sunTexture = preLoad.load("/static/sun-texture.jpg");
    var mercuryTexture = preLoad.load("/static/mercury-texture.jpg");
    var socketio = io();
    var Geometries = [];
    socketio.on("TX2", function (data) {
        Geometries = [];
        var collectedEntities = [];
        data.objects.forEach(obj => {
            collectedEntities.push(obj);
        });
        DisplayAllEntities(collectedEntities);
    });
    function DisplayAllEntities(objects) {
        var loader;
        objects.forEach(obj => {
            if (obj.geometry == "sphere") {
                if (obj.type != "ordinary_sphere") {
                    switch (obj.type) {
                        case "sun":
                            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: sunTexture });
                            break;
                        case "mercury":
                            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: mercuryTexture });
                            camera.position.z = obj.z + 500;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                var texture = loader.load(obj.texture)
                var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(obj.radius, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                Geometries.push(mesh);

            } else if (obj.geometry == "cube") {
                loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                var texture = loader.load(obj.texture)
                var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(obj.width, obj.height, obj.depth);

                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                mesh.position = {"x": obj.x, "y": obj.y, "z": obj.z}
                Geometries.push(mesh);

            }
            loader = null;
        });

        scene.children = [];
        scene.dispose();
        Geometries.forEach(obj => {
            scene.add(obj);
        });
        render();
    }
    function render() {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
```

The server just makes calculations about positions, and sends them to clients to render them.

I expect to get a lower CPU and GPU usage and a much lower load time, but the performance still remains the same.

Comment: Is TX2 for an init function or is it the game loop?

Comment: It is a server-side code emit, which executes 60 times a second. It sends packets for all entities' positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very inefficient to create each object every time you need to render it, and especially to load the corresponding textures. A better solution would be set up the objects beforehand, and then to update these objects continually. This would require

- a server emit for initializing (setting up objects, loading textures etc.)
- a server emit for game state updates (adding/removing items if needed)
- a server emit to update the positions. (this is the one that will execute 60 times per second)
- Each object to have a unique id given by the server at creation so that the client knows which object server references.

This involves a bit more effort but would boost performance greatly

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go.